# Is there a way to have easily scalable clients in Jitsi?

Tags: docker, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I'm trying to **measure the power consumption of Jitsi servers** with varying numbers of clients.

### current set-up:

- several different devices
- all connected locally with a switch to the server

### Problem : it is inefficient and unfeasible for scaling up.

- Is there a better way?
- Is there a way to have docker clients running with a virtual camera/audio?

I've considered trying to have clients run in docker.

I'm also aware that you can connect with different instances on the same device, but I'm trying to avoid this as I don't know if this will affect the results (since the server may only receive one video stream to decode, changing the power consumption recorded).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be a good idea to create :

- a `Dockerfile` for each "type" of device.
- a `Dockerfile` for your jitsi server

After that you can install `minikube` (a local standalone k8s cluster) to create :

- a `deployment` for each device (*using the created docker image just before*)  : you will be able to update the number of pods (instances of your devices) as you wish
- a `deployment` for your jitsi server (*using the created docker image just before*)

*i.e : you can set 100 pods of 'devices' if you want.*

Comment: For large numbers of clients this could work, I think. But as for having virtual video/audio feeds in the docker clients, I'd still need to find a way to make that feasible.